# How to find the issue when parsing an import csv for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

A BigQuery import job gives me this:

> Errors:
>   Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
>   Error detected while parsing row starting at position:943701703. ValueTrait:3

How do I find the point in the import file where it stopped so that I can have a look (and hopefully fix it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position value in the error message is the (uncompressed) byte offset for the row in the file at which the error occurred. The error message could probably benefit from a bit more elaboration for the value trait -- in this case it looks like there is data beyond the end of a quoted field value (either before the end of line or before the delimiter).

Comment: Is there any way to find that position? The file in question has 10m rows

Comment: I modified the python script mentioned here and it was successful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21560888/149998